# Eclipse can see resources which do not exist

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android development.

I created an Android project, and imported some images as resources.

Unfortunately, one of them contained a capital letter, which is illegal. I have first renamed, then removed the offending image. Then I delete all images, but Eclipse still insists they are there after clicking refresh refreshing and running clean several times.

Could anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: are you sure the file actually does not exist on the file system?

Comment: When you say clean, did you mean `Project` > `Clean`?

Comment: Yes try that. And look if you checked 'Build Automatically'

Comment: Yes, they are not on the disk, and there are no hidden files. YEs, I mean Project-> Clean. YEs, build Automatically is checked, should I uncheck it?

Comment: Well thanks Thommy, unchecnking Build Automatically seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Weird fix, but nice one @Thommy :)!

Comment: Does anyone know why this was the case? Or willing to venture an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0):

If the file actually exists in your workspace . Just Right Click the file and select Validate . It should be alright